# Laravel - Requesting data from two tables to pass to view

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have two tables, "accounts" and "Followups". I want to be able to pull the data through the FollowupController to pass to the view and run through a foreach loop.

for example; I have multiple rows of accounts in the accounts table that only certain rows will have a followup linked to it through a foreign key.
I want to be able to iterate through those follow ups. Pulling the data from the follow ups table is easy. But I'm not sure how to pull data from the accounts table in the same foreach loop.

This is what I have so far (obviously not working);

View:

```
@foreach($accounts as $account)
  {{$account->sName}}
  @foreach($followups as $followup)
    <div style="padding-bottom: 5px">
      <h5>{{$followup->followSubject}}</h5>
      <p><b>Date Created: </b> {{$followup->followCreateDate}}</p>
      <p><b>Follow Up By: </b> {{$followup->followUpEndDate}}</p>
      <p>{{$followup->followNotes}}</p>

    </div>
  @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Controller:

```
    public function index()
{
    $followups = Followup::all();
    $accounts = Account::all();
    return view('followups')->with('followups', $followups)
    ->with('accounts', Account::all());
}
```

Model for Accounts:

```
function followups() {
    return $this->hasMany(Followups::class);
}
```

Model for Follow ups:

```
public function account() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Account');
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do a relation in your model and then load the related data

Comment: you can join the tables with foreign key. Follow the url
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#joins

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz I just added my models that I currently have, but I'm still having difficultly loading the related data.

Comment: @KuldeepMishra I have attempted table joins, I get an error; 
(1/1) BadMethodCallException
Method join does not exist.

Comment: share your join code.

Comment: you can do relation also.

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/eager-loading-with-condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just eagerload them, those that have a follow up will be displayed:

```
public function index()
{ 
    $accounts = Account::with('followups')->get();
    return view('followups', ['accounts'=>$accounts]);
}
```

Then access them on the blade:

```
  @foreach($accounts as $account)
         {{$account->followups->attribute}}
  @endforeach
```

For more check Laravel [eageloading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: When I implement  this code I receive the following error;  

(1/1) FatalThrowableError
Class 'App\Followups' not found

Comment: `$account->followups->attribute` will throw `trying to get property of non-object` because is an array. Remember that `account` has many `followups`

Comment: ...Sorry yeah I had already done that but had a typo... I've been coding too long.. Sorry but this is the error I'm now receiving; 
(1/1) RelationNotFoundException
Call to undefined relationship [followup] on model [App\Account].
But I thought I had already defined the relationship in the model?

Comment: yeah I've already noticed and fixed that, now its just telling me "ErrorException Undefined variable: account" Which makes me think there is still a problem with my relationships..

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz how do i fix the property of non-object error?

Comment: iterate over the `$account->followups` array.